# Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門 最初の環境構築でDockerで行ったら、seleniumを使用したテストが通らない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rspec

下記の記事を参考にdockerで環境構築しました。
[【動画付き】Everyday RailsのサンプルアプリをRails 6で動かす際に必要なテストコードの変更点](https://blog.jnito.com/entry/2019/10/25/053521)

dockerのイメージがrubyしか入っていないので、下記の記事を参考にrubyのイメージとgoogle chromeのイメージでコンテナを作成してremoteで操作するようにしました。

[Failed to find Chrome binary について](https://qiita.com/yusuke_mrmt/items/4e38d031ea49cdd8834d)

capybara.rbは下記の記事を参考に変更しました。
[Dockerを導入後に、(Rspec)テストコードが完全に使い物にならなくなった件について②](https://qiita.com/tochisuke221/items/374359eb3cff1182ed6c)

dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  nodejs \
  imagemagick \
  vim \
  curl \
  yarn


WORKDIR /rspec-tutorial
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rspec-tutorial
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install
```

docker-compose

`http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub` にはwebコンテナから `curl http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub` で値が返ってきたので接続は上手くいっている気がします。

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    # portsは -pの役割
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    # volumesは -vの役割
    volumes:
      - '.:/rspec-tutorial'

    # ttyは -itのtを意味してる
    tty: true
    # -iを意味してる
    stdin_open: true
    environment: #以下追記
      - SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL=http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub
    depends_on:
      - selenium_chrome

  selenium_chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    logging:
      driver: none
```

vcr.rb

```
require "vcr"

VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/cassettes"
  config.hook_into :webmock
  config.ignore_localhost = true
  config.ignore_hosts 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
  config.configure_rspec_metadata!
end
```

capybara.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :remote_chrome do |app|
  url = ENV['SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL']
  caps = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'goog:chromeOptions' => {
      'args' => [
        'no-sandbox',
        'headless',
        'disable-gpu',
        'window-size=1680,1050'
      ]
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, url: url, desired_capabilities: caps)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    #driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
    Capybara.server_host = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)
    Capybara.app_host = "http://#{Capybara.server_host}"
    driven_by :remote_chrome
  end
end
Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.10.0'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'faker', require: false # for sample data in development
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers', require: !ENV['SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL']
  # Or use poltergeist and PhantomJS as an alternative to Selenium/Chrome
  # gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.15.0'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.3'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'geocoder'
```

エラーの内容 `bin/rspec` の実行結果一部
3つ出ていて上の２つもなぜそうなるか分からないのと "Message"の要素はあったので入力の部分が上手く行ってない気がします。 `VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:` ここがwebdriverの設定がうまくいってないために起きている気がします。

```
Notes
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead. (called from instance_exec at /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428)
  user uploads an attachment (FAILED - 1)

Projects
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead. (called from instance_exec at /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428)
  user creates a new project (FAILED - 2)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead. (called from instance_exec at /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428)
DEPRECATION WARNING: update_attributes is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (please, use update instead) (called from complete at /rspec-tutorial/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:67)
  user completes a project

Sign in
  user signs in

Sign-ups
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] `DeviseHelper#devise_error_messages!` is deprecated and will be
removed in the next major version.

Devise now uses a partial under "devise/shared/error_messages" to display
error messages by default, and make them easier to customize. Update your
views changing calls from:

    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

to:

    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

To start customizing how errors are displayed, you can copy the partial
from devise to your `app/views` folder. Alternatively, you can run
`rails g devise:views` which will copy all of them again to your app.
 (called from block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__4110300985041478851_70180839616580 at /rspec-tutorial/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:4)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead. (called from send_welcome_email at /rspec-tutorial/app/models/user.rb:51)
  user successfully signs up

Tasks
  user toggles a task (FAILED - 3)

Failures:

  1) Notes user uploads an attachment
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Message", with: "My book cover"
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field "Message" that is not disabled
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:314:in `block in synced_resolve'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:302:in `synced_resolve'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:37:in `find'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:92:in `fill_in'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:792:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/system/notes_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) Projects user creates a new project
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: "Test Project"
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field "Name" that is not disabled
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:314:in `block in synced_resolve'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:302:in `synced_resolve'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:37:in `find'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:92:in `fill_in'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:792:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  3) Tasks user toggles a task
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     3.1) Failure/Error: visit root_path
          
          VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
          
          
            ================================================================================
            An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
              GET http://172.23.0.3:45825/__identify__
          
            There is currently no cassette in use. There are a few ways
            you can configure VCR to handle this request:
          
              * If you're surprised VCR is raising this error
                and want insight about how VCR attempted to handle the request,
                you can use the debug_logger configuration option to log more details [1].
              * If you want VCR to record this request and play it back during future test
                runs, you should wrap your test (or this portion of your test) in a
                `VCR.use_cassette` block [2].
              * If you only want VCR to handle requests made while a cassette is in use,
                configure `allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true`. VCR will
                ignore this request since it is made when there is no cassette [3].
              * If you want VCR to ignore this request (and others like it), you can
                set an `ignore_request` callback [4].
          
            [1] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging
            [2] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/getting-started
            [3] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/allow-http-connections-when-no-cassette
            [4] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request
            ================================================================================
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:97:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:129:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:24:in `handle'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:144:in `block in <module:WebMock>'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `synchronize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `block in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:40:in `matches?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:73:in `block in request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `detect'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:64:in `response_for_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:79:in `request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `block in responsive?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `responsive?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:98:in `boot'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:88:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `new'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `current_session'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:45:in `page'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:24:in `go_to_project'
          # ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
          # -e:1:in `<main>'

     3.2) Failure/Error: raise VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError.new(vcr_request)
          
          VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
          
          
            ================================================================================
            An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
              GET http://172.23.0.3:45543/__identify__
          
            There is currently no cassette in use. There are a few ways
            you can configure VCR to handle this request:
          
              * If you're surprised VCR is raising this error
                and want insight about how VCR attempted to handle the request,
                you can use the debug_logger configuration option to log more details [1].
              * If you want VCR to record this request and play it back during future test
                runs, you should wrap your test (or this portion of your test) in a
                `VCR.use_cassette` block [2].
              * If you only want VCR to handle requests made while a cassette is in use,
                configure `allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true`. VCR will
                ignore this request since it is made when there is no cassette [3].
              * If you want VCR to ignore this request (and others like it), you can
                set an `ignore_request` callback [4].
          
            [1] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging
            [2] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/getting-started
            [3] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/allow-http-connections-when-no-cassette
            [4] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request
            ================================================================================
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:97:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:129:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:24:in `handle'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:144:in `block in <module:WebMock>'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `synchronize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `block in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:40:in `matches?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:73:in `block in request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `detect'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:64:in `response_for_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:79:in `request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `block in responsive?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `responsive?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:98:in `boot'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:88:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `new'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `current_session'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:45:in `page'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
          # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 12.52 seconds (files took 7.23 seconds to load)
70 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/system/notes_spec.rb:11 # Notes user uploads an attachment
rspec ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:4 # Projects user creates a new project
rspec ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:12 # Tasks user toggles a task
```

詳しい方見て頂けないでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

#### 追記

回答ありがとうございます。
回答の通り実行してみました。

`bundle exec rspec ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:4` を実行したのですが、`Projects`と表示されて、そこでターミナルが停止したので `bin/rspec` で最後まで実行しました。出力されたHTMLが下記のものなのですが、 `Name` は出力されているのでページ自体は問題ないように思えます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Projects</title>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-28980a99879b3e7c5e959443ff567e1dbf870a52e9621dd48342af6b26a5b19e.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/application-72847cdf4703e06466ef126657cf2a97a72b3dfbfa563f1a3a38ba43378d6c63.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Project Manager</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/users/edit">Aaron Sumner</a></li>
          <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

      
      <h1>New Project</h1>

<form action="/projects" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="project_name" type="text" name="project[name]" />
  </div>...
```

vcr.rb

下記のコードだとエラーが出力される

エラー内容

```
Failure/Error:
  config.ignore_requests do |request|
    # 正規表現で http://172.23.0.3:45825 のようなURLへのリクエストをVCRの対象外とする
    request.uri.match?(/^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+:\d+/)
  end

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `ignore_requests' for #<VCR::Configuration:0x0000561a4e5dddb0>
  Did you mean?  ignore_request
```

修正前のコード

```
# 以下のコードブロックを追加
config.ignore_requests do |request|
  # 正規表現で http://172.23.0.3:45825 のようなURLへのリクエストをVCRの対象外とする
  request.uri.match?(/^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+:\d+/)
end
```

修正後コード

```
# 以下のコードブロックを追加
  config.ignore_request do |request|
    # 正規表現で http://172.23.0.3:45825 のようなURLへのリクエストをVCRの対象外とする
    request.uri.match?(/^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+:\d+/)
  end
```

修正後のコードが出力するエラー

```
VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError.new(vcr_request)
          
          VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
          
          
            ================================================================================
            An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
              POST http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub/session
          
            There is currently no cassette in use. There are a few ways
            you can configure VCR to handle this request:
          
              * If you're surprised VCR is raising this error
                and want insight about how VCR attempted to handle the request,
                you can use the debug_logger configuration option to log more details [1].
              * If you want VCR to record this request and play it back during future test
                runs, you should wrap your test (or this portion of your test) in a
                `VCR.use_cassette` block [2].
              * If you only want VCR to handle requests made while a cassette is in use,
                configure `allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true`. VCR will
                ignore this request since it is made when there is no cassette [3].
              * If you want VCR to ignore this request (and others like it), you can
                set an `ignore_request` callback [4].
          
            [1] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging
            [2] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/getting-started
            [3] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/allow-http-connections-when-no-cassette
            [4] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request
            ================================================================================
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:97:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:129:in `on_unhandled_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/request_handler.rb:24:in `handle'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/vcr-6.0.0/lib/vcr/library_hooks/webmock.rb:144:in `block in <module:WebMock>'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `synchronize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:39:in `block in register_global_stub'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:40:in `matches?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:73:in `block in request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `detect'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:72:in `request_stub_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:64:in `response_for_request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:79:in `request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in `response_for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:77:in `request'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:588:in `execute'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:52:in `create_session'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:340:in `create_bridge'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/driver.rb:44:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:57:in `new'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:57:in `for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:23:in `browser'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:118:in `save_screenshot'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.15.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:763:in `save_screenshot'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
          # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 12.65 seconds (files took 5.04 seconds to load)
70 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/system/notes_spec.rb:11 # Notes user uploads an attachment
rspec ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:4 # Projects user creates a new project
rspec ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:12 # Tasks user toggles a task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門」翻訳チームの伊藤です。本書を読んでくださってどうもありがとうございます！

質問の件ですが、ふだんDockerを使っていないので、想像で回答します。

#### 1と2のエラーについて

ブラウザ上でテキスト入力ができないようですね。ただ、ログイン時のテキスト入力はうまくいってるようなので、もしかするとHTMLの出力がおかしいのかもしれません。

調査のために`save_page`メソッドを呼び出してください。

```
click_link "New Project"
save_page # この行を追加
fill_in "Name", with: "Test Project"
fill_in "Description", with: "Trying out Capybara"
click_button "Create Project"
```

それからこのテストにターゲットを絞って実行します。

```
bundle exec rspec ./spec/system/projects_spec.rb:4
```

テストが実行されると`tmp/capybara`の下に`capybara-202111190756363446470403.html`のような名前のファイルが作成されます。このHTMLを分析するとテキスト入力できない原因がわかるかもしれません。原因がわからない場合は、HTMLの出力内容を追記してください。

#### 3のエラーについて

`spec/support/vcr.rb` に追加した `config.ignore_localhost = true` で、「ローカルマシンへのアクセスはVCRの対象外とする」としているのですが、Dockerの場合は「ローカルマシン＝`localhost`」にならないのかもしれません。おそらく `172.23.0.3:45825` のようなIPとportを指定するんだと思いますが、この値は動的に変わりそうなので、正規表現を使って柔軟に対応できるようにした方が良さそうです。`spec/support/vcr.rb` に次の設定を追加してみてください。

```
config.ignore_localhost = true
config.ignore_hosts 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'

# 以下のコードブロックを追加
config.ignore_requests do |request|
  # 正規表現で http://172.23.0.3:45825 のようなURLへのリクエストをVCRの対象外とする
  request.uri.match?(/^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+:\d+/)
end

config.configure_rspec_metadata!
```

それぞれ試してみたらどうなったか、結果を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

### 追記

追記された箇所を見てみました。

#### 1と2のエラーについて

以下の部分のlabelタグがおかしいですね。

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="project_name" type="text" name="project[name]" />
  </div>
```

ここは `<label for="project_name">Name</label>` のようにfor属性付きで出力されないと、 `fill_in 'Name'`のようにlabelのテキストで`fill_in`できません(labelのfor属性とinputのid属性を一致させる必要がある)。

ただ、ふつうに`label`ヘルパーを使えばfor属性が自動的に出力されるはずなのですが、なぜ出力されないのか謎です。

以下のサンプルコードからコードを変えたりしていませんか？

https://github.com/everydayrails/everydayrails-rspec-2017/blob/master/app/views/projects/_form.html.erb

念のため、`app/views/projects/_form.html.erb` のコードと、`Gemfile.lock`の内容も見てみたいです。
というか、今動かそうとしているコード全体をGithubにpushしてもらえるとこちらの調査が捗りそうです。

#### 3のエラーについて

`An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle: POST http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub/session` というメッセージが見えるので、`selenium_chrome`というhostをVCRの対象外にすると良さそうです。`spec/support/vcr.rb`の`ignore_hosts`を以下のように指定してみてください。

```
config.ignore_hosts 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', 'selenium_chrome'
```

### 追記・その2

コードの共有ありがとうございます。自分のマシンにもDockerをインストールして動かしてみました。
たしかにエラーが再現したので、あれこれ試行錯誤して、最終的にテストを全部パスさせることができました。

[image: screenshot]

#### 修正点のdiff

テストが全パスした時点の `git diff` の結果を貼っておきます。それぞれどういう理由で変更したのかコメントを付けているので、必要に応じてwataruさんの環境で適用してみてください。

```
# M1 Mac向けの設定変更なので、たぶん対応不要
diff --git a/Dockerfile b/Dockerfile
index 6f5034e..bb418ca 100644
--- a/Dockerfile
+++ b/Dockerfile
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 FROM ruby:2.6.3
-RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
+RUN wget --quiet -O - /tmp/pubkey.gpg  https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
 RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   build-essential \
@@ -12,6 +12,6 @@ RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \


# 末尾に / を入れないとエラーが出た
 WORKDIR /rspec-tutorial
-COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rspec-tutorial
+COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rspec-tutorial/
 RUN bundle install


# M1 Mac用にnokogiriを再インストール + Capybaraが古くてエラーが出たので bundle update capybara を実行
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 5b9f5d0..3193e9b 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -68,13 +68,15 @@ GEM
       sassc (>= 2.0.0)
     builder (3.2.4)
     byebug (11.1.3)
-    capybara (2.15.4)
+    capybara (3.36.0)
       addressable
+      matrix
       mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
-      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
-      rack (>= 1.0.0)
-      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
-      xpath (~> 2.0)
+      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
+      rack (>= 1.6.0)
+      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
+      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
+      xpath (~> 3.2)
     childprocess (4.1.0)
     climate_control (0.2.0)
     coffee-rails (4.2.2)
@@ -129,6 +131,7 @@ GEM
     mail (2.7.1)
       mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
     marcel (1.0.2)
+    matrix (0.4.2)
     method_source (1.0.0)
     mime-types (3.4.1)
       mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
@@ -137,9 +140,11 @@ GEM
       nokogiri (~> 1)
       rake
     mini_mime (1.1.2)
+    mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
     minitest (5.14.4)
     nio4r (2.5.8)
-    nokogiri (1.12.5-x86_64-linux)
+    nokogiri (1.12.5)
+      mini_portile2 (~> 2.6.1)
       racc (~> 1.4)
     orm_adapter (0.5.0)
     paperclip (6.1.0)
@@ -289,8 +294,8 @@ GEM
     websocket-driver (0.7.5)
       websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
     websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
-    xpath (2.1.0)
-      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
+    xpath (3.2.0)
+      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
     zeitwerk (2.5.1)

 PLATFORMS


# Rails 6.0.4.1を使っているので、 load_defaults に6.0を指定。こうしないとlabelタグにfor属性が付かない
diff --git a/config/application.rb b/config/application.rb
index c6e90ab..e7d702b 100644
--- a/config/application.rb
+++ b/config/application.rb
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
 module Projects
   class Application < Rails::Application
     # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
-    config.load_defaults 5.1
+    config.load_defaults 6.0

     # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
     # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers


# volumes の追加と変更はインストールしたgemを永続化させるため
# SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL は / が重なっていてエラーが出たので修正
# seleniarm/standalone-chromium はM1 Mac用のimage
# ports の追加はこうしないと tasks_spec.rb が動かなかった
# logging はあって困るものではないので出力するようにした
diff --git a/docker-compose.yml b/docker-compose.yml
index 073bc2f..e6129db 100644
--- a/docker-compose.yml
+++ b/docker-compose.yml
@@ -9,17 +9,21 @@ services:
     # volumesは -vの役割
     volumes:
       - '.:/rspec-tutorial'
+      - gem_data:/usr/local/bundle

     # ttyは -itのtを意味してる
     tty: true
     # -iを意味してる
     stdin_open: true
     environment: #以下追記
-      - SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL=http://selenium_chrome:4444//wd/hub
+      - SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL=http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub
     depends_on:
       - selenium_chrome

   selenium_chrome:
-    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
-    logging:
-      driver: none
\ No newline at end of file
+    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium
+    ports:
+      - '4444:4444'
+
+volumes:
+  gem_data:


# 変更の理由は https://blog.jnito.com/entry/2019/10/25/053521 を参照。
diff --git a/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb b/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
index b931446..b8e6c2d 100644
--- a/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
+++ b/spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ RSpec.describe TasksController, type: :controller do
       sign_in user
       get :show, format: :json,
         params: { project_id: project.id, id: task.id }
-      expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json"
+      expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     end
   end

@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ RSpec.describe TasksController, type: :controller do
       sign_in user
       post :create, format: :json,
         params: { project_id: project.id, task: new_task }
-      expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json"
+      expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     end

     it "adds a new task to the project" do


# Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless はおそらく不要なので削除
diff --git a/spec/support/capybara.rb b/spec/support/capybara.rb
index fbb8dfb..7040dc9 100644
--- a/spec/support/capybara.rb
+++ b/spec/support/capybara.rb
@@ -16,8 +16,6 @@ Capybara.register_driver :remote_chrome do |app|
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, url: url, desired_capabilities: caps)
 end

-Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
-
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.before(:each, type: :system) do
     driven_by :rack_test
@@ -31,4 +29,3 @@ RSpec.configure do |config|
   end
 end
 Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
-Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless


# 以前伝えた修正点が適用されていなかったので、適用した
diff --git a/spec/support/vcr.rb b/spec/support/vcr.rb
index 61088b5..1f0c627 100644
--- a/spec/support/vcr.rb
+++ b/spec/support/vcr.rb
@@ -5,5 +5,9 @@ VCR.configure do |config|
   config.hook_into :webmock
   config.ignore_localhost = true
   config.ignore_hosts 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', 'selenium_chrome'
+  config.ignore_request do |request|
+    # 正規表現で http://172.23.0.3:45825 のようなURLへのリクエストをVCRの対象外とする
+    request.uri.match?(/^http:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+:\d+/)
+  end
   config.configure_rspec_metadata!
 end


# save_page はデバッグ用のコードなので削除
diff --git a/spec/system/projects_spec.rb b/spec/system/projects_spec.rb
index 1f7beb3..83194a9 100644
--- a/spec/system/projects_spec.rb
+++ b/spec/system/projects_spec.rb
@@ -12,7 +12,6 @@ RSpec.describe "Projects", type: :system do

     expect {
       click_link "New Project"
-      save_page
       fill_in "Name", with: "Test Project"
       fill_in "Description", with: "Trying out Capybara"
       click_button "Create Project"
```

#### その他（ひとりごと）

テストは全パスしているものの、警告は結構たくさん出ています。 `.rspec` から `--warnings` を消せば少し減りますが、それでもまだ警告は出ています。
https://blog.jnito.com/entry/2019/10/15/085932 でブログを書いたときからすでに2年が経っていて、この情報すら古くなりつつあるので、そろそろ2021年版（2022年版？）のセットアップ手順をまとめないといけないな〜と考えています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
内容を実行してみたのですが、エラーがまだ出ています。

Comment: @wataru 追記ありがとうございます。回答を編集しました。

Comment: コードの変更がないか確認とignoreの設定を追記の物に変更してみたのですが、結果は変わらなかったです。コードをリポジトリに追加しました。お手隙の際にご確認よろしくお願い致します。
https://github.com/wimpykid719/tutorial-rspec

Comment: @wataru コードの共有ありがとうございます！おかげで僕の環境ではテストを全パスさせることができました。追記した回答を確認してください。

Comment: dockerをインストールしての検証までありがとうございます。
とても助かりました。学習を進めていこうと思います。
自分の環境でもテスト全てパス出来ました。
2022年版のセットアップ手順をお願い致します。動画等もあり、とても分かりやすかったです。
dockerでの環境構築などもあるととてもありがたいです。

Comment: @wataru 解決して良かったです！Dockerのサポートまで手が回るかどうかはわかりませんが、環境手順のアップデートはそのうちやりたいと思います〜。